# is there a way to WaterMarking a screenshot image in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot

i had a task inorder to compare the screenshot text with the text data in the excelsheet for lot of data's, i just want to know in selenium(java) is their possibility of watermarking the data in the particular screenshoot  whatever im capturing in the webpage

Comment: What should this "Watermarking" do?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not providing any such feature.

You need to use third party libraries like :-

https://gist.github.com/madan712/4026080

You can have a look to the "Drawing the Watermark" section of http://web.archive.org/web/20080324030029/http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/02/watermarking-images-in-java-servlet.html

Or you may use the GIF4J library http://www.gif4j.com/java-gif4j-pro-gif-image-watermark.htm#gifimagewatermarkapply

Hope it will help you :)